# Google Analytics API call from behind a NAT gateway is filtered by bot filter

Tags: curl, google-analytics, filtering, bots, google-analytics-api

I want to use Google Analytics API for a server-side analytics implementation.

A quick testing call to the Google Analytics API using a curl command from my Google Cloud Platform VM behind the NAT gateway results in no traffic appearing in the G/A real-time view. The curl command returns a 200 response code so it is definitely reaching the www.google-analytics.com/colllect endpoint.

If I turn off the Bot Filtering in the Google Analytics view settings and resubmit the curl command, then the traffic does appear.

The same curl command from anywhere else (e.g. my desktop) generates traffic in G/A real-time view - whether Bot Filtering is enabled or not.

How do I keep Bot Filtering enabled while still allowing Google Analytics traffic from my VM behind a NAT gateway?

If it helps, my curl command looks like this:

```
curl -s -H 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/5
37.36' -q https://www.google-analytics.com/collect -d "tid=UA-XXXXXX-1" -d "t=event" -d "ec=category" -d "ea=testAction" -d "v=1" -d "cid=1" -d "z=1" --output /dev/null
```

**Edit:** That my VM is behind a NAT gateway is more relevant than being behind a load balancer

Comment: it's quite a common issue since some time ago and there's actually no fix for that other than disabling bot filtering.
Sometimes switching to POST requests helps

Comment: Hi @ДмитроБулах yes I'm already using POST in the example curl command above.